# Inavlid credential happen when requesting BACKEND API

Tags: symfony, security

I'am working on a project which has an API built with symfony2 as backend.  After logging in and getting token when I try to sent get request with generated token this issue happend

```
-->"code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid credentials"
```

attached my **config.yml** and **security.yml** setting

security.yml file

[image]

[requet get to backend api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYbJV.png)

Comment: How do you authenticate to perform a request to the api, which url return you this error response ?...

Comment: I used this url  http://api_drop.neobe.com/app_dev.php/api/Dasboard/client/20 I'm trying to get a user from database .in the action I check if headers request contain generated token still not expirated  . let me attached new screenshot of request

Comment: Why have you to check the token JWT token mannualy ? Lexit use your token and set the user connected in the application context (available in the token storage) by `$this->getUser()` in your controller. Can you provide your controller code ? By the way I tried a request to your route

Comment: when the token is generated I stored it in database in table MYTOKENAPI map with user

Comment: Please come here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153218/inavlid-credential-happen-when-requesting-backend-api

Comment: I try to go there but I  must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there

Comment: I'm not able to paste here the controller code , because it's too long and the editor not allow it . It seem like when I call the controler the code inside its not execute  maybe firewall not allow to execute it? how can I share  my complete code with you ?

Comment: Your problem appear before your controller, the error you get is returned by lexit because you aren't authenticate. Have you got an example of another endpoints using this kind of authentification ? Please give me your `config.yml`

Comment: sorry but no I'm just starting my project . how its possible that I'm not authentificate , I get a token an use it in header  of request ,I have  check vhos and  I already add     RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1] please help

Comment: Il me semble que tu es français. Je viens de voir ta requête avec Postman, il me semble qu'il y a une erreur. Il faut mettre `Authorization: Bearer tonToken` est ce que après ça le message d'erreur a changé ? Tu devrais essayer d'ajouter des listeners à lexit pour essayer de déterminer qu'est qu'il se passe mal dans l'authentification. Je te conseille de lire attentivement ces docs https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/tree/master/Resources/doc
Pas facile de t'aider plus que ça, mais dit toi qu'une fois que c'est en place c'est bon !

Comment: ouffffffff avant tout  merci  oui en fait j'oubliais le Bearer l'erreur n'est plus la meme  du coup je me retrouve avec un No route found for \"GET /api/Dasboard/client/listcommandes/listcommandes/20\"

Comment: Haaa cool ça :) Tu connais le [profiler](http://api_drop.neobe.com/app_dev.php/_profiler/latest?panel=router)  symfony ? Ca va t'aider à debugger tout tes bugs, là c'est juste que tu n'as pas définit de route pour cette url. Tu peux valider ma réponse stp ?

Comment: non je ne connais pas le profiler symfony par contre je pense avoir definit la route direct dans le controleur    /**
     * liste des commandes d'un client 
     * @Route("/Dasboard/client/listcommandes/{idclient}", methods={"GET"},name="listcommandes")
     * @View
     *
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *   resource = true,
     *   description="liste toutes les commandes d'un client",
     *
     * )
     *
     *

Comment: Le routing n'a pas de rapport avec ton post qui est sur un problème d'authentification par JWT auquel je t'ai répondu dans ma réponse. Pour le routing je te laisse fouiller dans la doc' et utiliser le profiler symfony le problème est très simple là

Comment: ok merci  beaucoup !

Comment: Hum hum tu n'as pas validé la réponse haha. J'essaye de monter ma réput :D

Comment: oups désolé je le la valide tout de suite  après avoir fixer le bug précédent  et en rajoutant le Bearer j'ai  comme erreur {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid JWT Token"
} en le retirant j'ai plutot  {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid credentials"
}

Comment: après un autre test je constate que en effectuant la meme requete  sans  le /api configurer dans le par-feu tout se passe bien

Comment: Tu t'en ai sortit avec ton routing ?

Comment: Bonjour tout roule  bien par contre je n'arrive pas a validé ta réponse  merci de me dire quoi faire !

Comment: Haa cool ça :) A gauche de ma réponse, en dessous du up et down vote tu as une flèche pour valider. Alors symfony tu kiffs ?

Comment: oui Symfony c'est une veritable tuerie , ca y je crois avoir validé ta réponse merci de me dire si c'est bien le cas

Comment: Et encore tu verras c'est que le début de ton long apprentissage haha. Non c'est pas le cas ^^' C'est une genre de flèche validé grise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that your  postman request is malformated

The correct format for the Authorization bearer header is:

```
Authorization: Bearer yourToken
```

Tell me if the error message change !

I hope this will solve your issue

Comment: always the same issue

Comment: after add Bearer this message error happen {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid JWT Token"
}

Comment: After another test I find that by making the same request without the / api configure in the fire all goes well